# NPE on spring autowires form TestExecutionListener

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit4, spring-test

This might have been coded wrongly, but any idea how it should be done is appreciated.

---

I have this class `TestClass` which needs to inject many service class. Since I can't use `@BeforeClass` on `@Autowired` objects, I result on using `AbstractTestExecutionListener`. Everything was working as expected but when I'm on `@Test` blocks, all objects are evaluated `null`.

Any idea how to solve this?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ProjectConfig.class })
@TestExecutionListeners({ TestClass.class })
public class TestClass extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @Autowired private FirstService firstService;
    // ... other services

    // objects needs to initialise on beforeTestClass and afterTestClass
    private First first;
    // ...

    // objects needs to be initialised on beforeTestMethod and afterTestMethod
    private Third third;
    // ...

    @Override public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        testContext.getApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);

        first = firstService.setUp();
    }

    @Override public void beforeTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        third = thirdService.setup();
    }

    @Test public void testOne() {
        first = someLogicHelper.recompute(first);
        // ...
    }

    // other tests

    @Override public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        thirdService.tearDown(third);
    }

    @Override public void afterTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        firstService.tearDown(first);
    }

}

@Service
public class FirstService {
    // logic
}
```

Comment: Make sure, services you are auto-wiring has annotated with **Sterio-type-annotation**

Comment: All services are using `org.springframework.stereotype.Service` annotation.

Answer (score 4):

For starters, having your test class implement `AbstractTestExecutionListener` is not a good idea. A `TestExecutionListener` should be implemented in a stand-alone class. So you might want to rethink that approach.

In any case, your current configuration is broken: you disabled all default `TestExecutionListener` implementations.

To include the defaults, try the following configuration instead.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ProjectConfig.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = TestClass.class, mergeMode = MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public class TestClass extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {
    // ...
}
```

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: I'm considering moving `AbstractTestExecutionListener` to a stand-alone class/es. However, I just don't know how to access the objects created on each phase (`beforeTestClass` and `beforeTestMethod`) in run-time of each `@Test` of `TestClass` without persisting to any database

Comment: This answer only solved `null` of `@Autowired` global variables. The global variables initialised during `beforeTestClass` and `beforeTestMethod` are still evaluated `null` under `@Test` method/s.